# Determine if a function $T : E_3\rightarrow E_3$ is injective, surjective or bijective

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T:E_3\rightarrow E_3$ be a funcion defined by $T(\mathbf{v})=\mathbf{v}\land(\mathbf{i}+\mathbf{j}+\mathbf{k})$. Establish if the function is injective, surjective or bijective.

My attempt: the function is clearly injective, but what about surjectivity?

Thanks

Comment: what is $\wedge$?

Comment: vectorial product

Comment: oh. then distribute over the sum and symplify

Comment: it is linear, and since $E_3$ is finite dimensional. it is obvious that injectivity gives surjectivity.

Comment: get the matrix fot $T$ and check the $\det$

Answer (score 0):

The vector product points in a direction perpendicular to the plane containing $\mathbf v$ and $(\mathbf i+\mathbf j+\mathbf k)$, and has a magnitude equal to parallelogram formed by the two vectors (and their sum).  i.e. $\|\mathbf v\| \|\mathbf i+\mathbf j+\mathbf k\| \sin\theta$

There exists a $\mathbf u$ that lie in the same plane $\mathbf v$ and $(\mathbf i+\mathbf j+\mathbf k)$ and not parallel to either.  For any $\mathbf u$ there is  some scaling factor $c$ such that $T(c\mathbf u) = T(\mathbf v)$.

$T(\mathbf v)$ is not an injection.

Is it a surjection?

there is no $\mathbf v$ such that $T(\mathbf v) = \mathbf i+\mathbf j+\mathbf k$

$T(\mathbf v)$ is not surjective.